# How to split a string with a delimiter that can be repeated adjacent without getting empty parts?

Tags: c#, string, split, delimiter

How to split a string using a delimiter when the delimiter can be next to each other and the first delimiter should be part of the string?

Eg:

```
ABC::XYZ:QUI
```

The split should be:

```
1) ABC:
2) XYZ
3) QUI
```

`Split(':')` does not works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may split on the regex pattern `:(?!:)`:

```cs
string input = "ABC::XYZ:QUI";
string[] parts = Regex.Split(input, @":(?!:)");
foreach (string part in parts)
{
    Console.WriteLine(part);
}
```

This prints:

```
ABC:
XYZ
QUI
```

The regex here uses a negative lookahead to ensure that we only split/consume on `:` which is not followed by another `:`.